# Content Dialog does not display after database insert query - UWP App

Tags: c#, uwp

I cannot get a UWP content dialog to display after executing a database insert query. Below is the code I have written. The Content dialog displays as it should when the insert query code is commented out. Am I missing something? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
private async void Admin_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    String selItem = TaskCombo.SelectedValue.ToString();
    dbDetail.AddAdminData(selItem, SettingTxt.Text);
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentDialog infoDialog = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentDialog()
    {
       Title = "Alert",
       Content = "Records entered successfully",
       CloseButtonText = "OK"
   };
   Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentDialogResult result = await infoDialog.ShowAsync();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an open data reader associated with the connection that was open and needed to be closed first. The db query was executing successfully, however the content dialogue could not be display because of the open data reader.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define  `String selItem` as property  like this `String selItem{set;get;}=TaskCombo.SelectedValue.ToString();`

Comment: the problem was not with String selItem but with the execution of the query so your suggestion did not solve the problem.